# How to assign cssClass to button inside ActionSheetController in Ionic 5 Angular app?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to add a CSS class to a button inside an ActionSheetController in my Ionic 5 Angular app, but the class isn't being assigned.

I've looked up some solutions online which suggest placing the CSS code in `app.component.scss`, I have tried that but it is still not working.

I'm creating the Controller in `mechanic.page.ts` below:

```
this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
      header: 'Choose an Action',
      cssClass: 'myPage',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Book Appointment',
          cssClass: 'myActionSheetBtnStyle',
          icon: 'calendar-outline',
          handler: () => {
            this.goToProfile(mechanicId);
          }
        }
      ]
    }).then(actionSheetEl => {
      actionSheetEl.present();
    });
```

And here is the CSS in `app.component.scss`:

```
.myPage {
    .myActionSheetBtnStyle {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

When I open the Controller, the button is not red. Can someone please tell me what changes I need to make in order for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add it to `app.component.scss`. It should be in `global.scss` in app folder. Also it's good practice to use css variables to style ionic components. In this case it should be something like:

```
.myPage {
  .myActionSheetBtnStyle {
    --button-color: red;
  }
}
```